# Multiplication of two arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multiplication

I have two numpy arrays:

```
x = numpy.array([1, 2])
y = numpy.array([3, 4])
```

And I would like to create a matrix of elements products:

```
[[3, 6],
 [4, 8]]
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use the `outer` function of `np.multiply` (and transpose if you want the same order as in your question):

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(x, y).T
array([[3, 6],
       [4, 8]])
```

Most ufuncs in NumPy have this useful `outer` feature (`add`, `subtract`, `divide`, etc.). As [@Akavall suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29848822/3923281), `np.outer` is equivalent for the multiplication case here.

Alternatively, [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can perform the multiplication and transpose in one go:

```
>>> np.einsum('i,j->ji', x, y)
array([[3, 6],
       [4, 8]])
```

A third approach is to insert a new axis in one the arrays and then multiply, although this is a little more verbose:

```
>>> (x[:, np.newaxis] * y).T
array([[3, 6],
       [4, 8]])
```

---

For those interested in performance, here are the timings of the operations, from quickest to slowest, on two arrays of length 15:

```
In [70]: x = np.arange(15)
In [71]: y = np.arange(0, 30, 2)
In [72]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j->ji', x, y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.88 µs per loop
In [73]: %timeit np.multiply.outer(x, y).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
In [74]: %timeit (x[:, np.newaxis] * y).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.68 µs per loop
In [75]: %timeit np.outer(x, y).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you use `np.outer`.

```
In [7]: x = np.array([1, 2])

In [8]: y = np.array([3, 4])

In [10]: np.outer(x,y).T
Out[10]: 
array([[3, 6],
       [4, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

B = np.multiply.outer(x, y).T

link:
http://pchanial.github.io/python-for-data-scientists/auto_examples/ufunc_matrices.html

here is a good tutorial for these question
this address can help :[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial)